# Unable to control UICollectionView using property

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

SO, I have a property to a UICollectionView Object

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewVARIABLE;
```

I held control and dragged the mouse, it's all linked up.

my problem is that it doesn't seem to actually work.

I try calling

```
[self.collectionViewVARIABLE registerClass:[MFH_mainfeed_CondensedViewCell class]   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MainIpadFeedCell"];
```

I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MainIpadFeedCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

If I put this call within cellForItemAtIndexPath using collectionView instead of the variable, it works.

I've tried the following on a button click, also nothing.

```
self.collectionViewVARIABLE.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

I have been at this for three days.  My head hurts.  Can somebody please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Post your actual error messages. Also, log self.collectionViewVARIABLE and see what it gives.

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionView.m:2249

Comment: And what does the log of self.collectionViewVARIABLE show?

Comment: pretty sure that when i add the reference to the property it's not adding it to the UICollectionView object

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MainIpadFeedCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Are you going to answer my question? What does the log of self.collectionViewVARIABLE show?

Comment: there is a separate log for properties?  where can I access that?  the only long I know of right now is the one of the bottom of Xcode.

Comment: No, there's not a separate log for properties, just put NSLog(@"%@",self.collectionViewVARIABLE) in viewDidLoad and report what you get.

Comment: Do you have a `MFH_mainfeed_CondensedViewCell` class defined either in a nib or a standalone .h/.m class file?

Comment: Alfie - Yeah, it's in it's own h/m.  Like I said, if I register it within the cellforitematindexpath, using collectionView, it works.  it's just not working when I use the property.